# Laravel5: Many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I have just started laravel5, but i haven't seen the model folder just like laravel4.
My questions are.

1.Where model folder reside in laravel5?

2.How many to manay relationship handle in laravel5?

I have the following scenario.

**Role Table** 
fields
**.** id
**.** role_name

**User Table**
**.** id
**.** username
**.** email
**.** password

pivot table
**role_user**
 **.** id
 **.** role_id
 **.** user_id

Comment: Please any one provide me the authentic resources form where i can start the laravel 5 because i have project and i need to upgrade it into laravel5.

Comment: Upgrade from 4.2 to 5 is so easy: Read the doc http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0 Just remember to add "use namespace/class" for each class you use in your controllers. And add namespace to your controllers will help too with routing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is not one. Models reside in the `App/` folder. As this is where the User model resides. Create your own folder to have one.
2. The documentation will cover this, found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many). This will go through how the relationship is set up within your relevant model.

   ```
   public function roles(){  
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'Pivot_table_name', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');  
   }
   ```

Please Note: Pretty much everything is covered within the documentation.

Now that you have your relation, you can call it like so on your user model `$user = User::with('roles')->find(1);` This will eager load your role on to the model for you, and can be accessed like so; `$user->roles`.

The documentation also covers querying relationships using the `whereHas` method found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations).

Answer (score 0):

Your application model should be like this > `app/Model/Role.php`

Set `namespace App\Model;` to all model files under app/Model.

Many to Many Relationship

> User.php

```
public function roles()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Role');
}
```

> Role.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Now you can use like this

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) 
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The model files are in `app` directory. When you install a fresh laravel, you should see a `User.php` file under `app` directory.

In your `Role` model, you should define a function:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

In your `User` model, you should define a function:

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

And if you want to get roles which belongs to user(s):

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $roles = $user->roles;
}
```

If you want to get users under one role:

```
$users = $role->users;

foreach($users as $user){
    //
}
```

These are "lazy loading", only load relationships when you access them.

[Here for more about model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent)
[Here for more about relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)